# Jmeter XML API Response and JDBC response value matching order

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, sql

Jmeter XML API Response and JDBC response value matching order. Do you think this order is correct? (Xpath reference name is using in jdbc request)

[image]

**more details given below**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer for this just moved Response assertion under JDBC request[other screenshots are remain same]. Thank you all.

[image]